# How to make an epub look good?

Tags: adobe-indesign, ebook, epub

I would like to design an ebook in InDesign but I am struggling with the formatting. The book it looks bad in epub format. I made research and I understand that flowing text will not be perfect because it will be adjusted by the user. But how can I keep the basics like a line break after the paragraphs? How to make the contents page look good besides just the blue links? It will be published on Kindle and other publishing pages online. If it is not possible to do anything about the styling is it even worth to do it in InDesign?

Comment: While I do not consider this question to be off-topic here, note that there is an [entire SE site dedicated to ebooks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/), where you probably get a better answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I will search it there!